# Primefaces autocomplete null pointer exception

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, autocomplete

I searched in old questions but I found nothing useful; I googled also a lot
I have a simple primefaces autocomplete so defined:

```
<p:autoComplete id="comNascita" 
value="#{gestioneDomandaResFormBean.datiDomanda.datiAnagrafici.comuneNascita}" 
required="true" 
converter="deComuneConverter"
forceSelection="true" 
var="comune" 
itemLabel="#{comune.descrizione}" 
label="#{ui['ui.res.creaDomanda.crea.domanda.form.comuneNascita']}"
itemValue="#{comune}" 
emptyMessage="Nullo"
completeMethod="#{decodificheBeanSvil.completeComuni}" 
size="55" 
minQueryLength="2"
styleClass="w100" 
cache="true" 
widgetVar="comNascitaWV" 
maxResults="10"/>
```

This is my converter:

```
@FacesConverter("deComuneConverter")
public class DeComuneConverter implements Converter 
{

    protected final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    private DeComuneEJB deComuneManager = null;
    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) 
    {
        if (value == null || value.trim().equals("")) 
        {
            if( logger.isDebugEnabled() )
            {
                logger.debug("Metodo getAsObject. Passato un value nullo o vuoto <"+value+">. Restituisco null");
            }
            return null;
        } 
        else 
        {
            DeComune deComune = null;
            try 
            {
                deComune = deComuneManager.findById(value);
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                if( logger.isWarnEnabled() )
                {

                    logger.warn("Errore nella converter dei comuni; "+e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            }
            return deComune;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value == null ||  (value instanceof String && ((String)value).trim().equals(""))) 
        {
            if( logger.isDebugEnabled() )
            {
                logger.debug("Metodo getAsString. Passato un value nullo o vuoto <"+value+">; restituisco stringa vuota"); 
            }
            return "";
        } else {
            return String.valueOf(((DeComune) value).getCodCom());
        }
    }
    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() throws Exception
    {
        InitialContext ic = null;
        try
        {
            ic = new InitialContext();
            deComuneManager = (DeComuneEJB) ic.lookup("java:module/"+DeComuneEJB.class.getSimpleName());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            if( logger.isErrorEnabled() )
            {
                logger.error("Errore nella ricerca JNDI dell'EJB per i comuni", e);
            }
            throw e;
        }
        finally 
        {
            if( ic != null )
            {
                ic.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my bean with the complete method:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "decodificheBeanSvil")
@ApplicationScoped
public class DecodificheBeanSvil implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5773268651349037154L;

    protected static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(DecodificheBeanSvil.class);

    protected Date currentDate;

    @PostConstruct
    protected void postConstruct() {
        currentDate = new Date();
    }
    public GenereEnum[] getGenereList() {
        return GenereEnum.values();
    }
    public List<DeComune> completeComuni(String startsWith)
    {
        List<DeComune> result = new ArrayList<DeComune>();
        Map<String, DeComune> comuniFake = FakeUtils.getComuniEr();
        Iterator<String> chiaviIterator = comuniFake.keySet().iterator();
        while (chiaviIterator.hasNext()) {
            String chiave = chiaviIterator.next();
            if( chiave.startsWith(startsWith.toLowerCase()) )
            {
                result.add(comuniFake.get(chiave));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

This is my DeComune POJO:

```
public class DeComune implements Serializable, Comparable<DeComune> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6250752442360948142L;
    private String codCom;
    private String descrizione;
    private String cap;

    public DeComune() {
        super();
    }

    public DeComune(String codCom, String descrizione, String cap) {
        super();
        this.codCom = codCom;
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
        this.cap = cap;
    }

    public String getCodCom() {
        return codCom;
    }

    public void setCodCom(String codCom) {
        this.codCom = codCom;
    }

    public String getDescrizione() {
        return descrizione;
    }

    public void setDescrizione(String descrizione) {
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
    }

    public String getCap() {
        return cap;
    }

    public void setCap(String cap) {
        this.cap = cap;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(DeComune o) {
        return this.descrizione.compareTo(o.getDescrizione());
    }
}
```

This is my FakeUtils

```
public abstract class FakeUtils {

    private static List<String> elencoComuniFake;
    private static Map<String, DeComune> elencoDeComuneFake;
    public static List<DeComune> fakeComuni()
    {
        elencoDeComuneFake = getMap();
        List<DeComune> result = new ArrayList<DeComune>(elencoComuniFake.size());
        result.addAll(elencoDeComuneFake.values());
        return result;
    }
    public static Map<String, DeComune> getComuniEr()
    {
        if( elencoDeComuneFake == null )
        {
            elencoDeComuneFake = getMap();
        }
        return elencoDeComuneFake;
    }
    public static DeComune getById( String id )
    {
        if( elencoDeComuneFake == null )
        {
            elencoDeComuneFake = getMap();
        }
        return elencoDeComuneFake.get(id.trim().toLowerCase());
    }
    private static Map<String, DeComune> getMap()
    {
        if( elencoDeComuneFake == null )
        {
            elencoComuniFake = elencoComuniFake();

            elencoDeComuneFake = new HashMap<String, DeComune>(elencoComuniFake.size());
            for (String nomeComune : elencoComuniFake) 
            {
                elencoDeComuneFake.put(nomeComune.trim().toLowerCase(), new DeComune(nomeComune, nomeComune, nomeComune));
            }
        }
        return elencoDeComuneFake;
    }
    private static List<String> elencoComuniFake()
    {
        if( elencoComuniFake == null )
        {
            elencoComuniFake = new ArrayList<String>();
            elencoComuniFake.add("Agazzano");
            elencoComuniFake.add("Albareto");
        }
        return elencoComuniFake;
    }

}
```

When I type something in the autocomplet field I get the following exception:

```
11:33:07,235 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:20000-3) Error Rendering View[/secure/domanda/_form/creaDomanda.xhtml]: javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startMetadataIfNecessary(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:303) [primefaces-6.0.jar:6.0]
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startUpdate(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:142) [primefaces-6.0.jar:6.0]
    at org.omnifaces.context.OmniPartialViewContext$OmniPartialResponseWriter.startUpdate(OmniPartialViewContext.java:300) [omnifaces-2.0.jar:2.0]
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:541) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-03.jar:2.1.29-03]
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-03.jar:2.1.29-03]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1611) [jsf-api-2.1.29-03.jar:2.1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1622) [jsf-api-2.1.29-03.jar:2.1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1622) [jsf-api-2.1.29-03.jar:2.1]
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:383) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-03.jar:2.1.29-03]
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:302) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-03.jar:2.1.29-03]
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:57) [primefaces-6.0.jar:6.0]
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:183) [jsf-api-2.1.29-03.jar:2.1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:973) [jsf-api-2.1.29-03.jar:2.1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1778) [jsf-api-2.1.29-03.jar:2.1]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:426) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-03.jar:2.1.29-03]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-03.jar:2.1.29-03]
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.application.PrettyViewHandler.renderView(PrettyViewHandler.java:163) [prettyfaces-jsf2-3.3.3.jar:]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:286) [jsf-api-2.1.29-03.jar:2.1]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:286) [jsf-api-2.1.29-03.jar:2.1]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-03.jar:2.1.29-03]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-03.jar:2.1.29-03]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-03.jar:2.1.29-03]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:604) [jsf-api-2.1.29-03.jar:2.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145) [prettyfaces-jsf2-3.3.3.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:840) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:622) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:560) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:137) [prettyfaces-jsf2-3.3.3.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at it.eng.sil.res.controller.filter.VerificaAccessoFilter.doFilter(VerificaAccessoFilter.java:93) [classes:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter.doFilter(HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter.java:75) [cas-client-core-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:107) [cas-client-core-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractTicketValidationFilter.doFilter(AbstractTicketValidationFilter.java:201) [cas-client-core-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:76) [cas-client-core-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at it.eng.sil.res.controller.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:95) [classes:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:165) [jboss-as-web-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:372) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:679) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:931) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.util.ResourceUtils.filterStylesheets(ResourceUtils.java:96) [primefaces-6.0.jar:6.0]
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startMetadataIfNecessary(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:287) [primefaces-6.0.jar:6.0]
    ... 64 more
```

I'm stopped here from a couple of hours... Does anybody know what my issue can be?

Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1808 I think this NPE masks another problem. There may be another exception happening before that, or some kind of invalid state happening without an explicit exception. Try upgrading to PF 6.1 and see.

Comment: @VsevolodGolovanov sadly not working... after upgrading to PF 6.1 the ajax call in autocomplete didn't start at all

Comment: Look at your browser console for JS errors when opening the page.

Comment: No error on console... it simply decided to not work :)

Comment: I got it... I had a <form> tag instead of <h:form>......